# Connection between multiple Rasp Pi based on win10 IoT

Tags: windows-iot, networking

I'm currently working on a project using 3 RaspPi 2 based on Win10 IoT. For my project, I need to send Arrays from one RPi (called here "master") to the others (called here "slaves"). I'm programming an app on Visual Studio.

I think that the best way to have a wireless communication is to set up an ad-hoc network on the "master" and connect the "slaves" to it.

Here are the questions : 
*Am I on the right way ?* 
*Admitting that yes, I didn't find any information on internet to do that (and assuming I'm somehow a newbie on win10IoT) I failed to perform this task. Any idea how to do it ? :D*

Comment: yes ad-hoc is the right way to think of it. Use __Ralink RT3570 Driver__ based WiFi Adapters to achieve ad hoc mode.  I do not use Windows 10 IoT so I could not help further but the initial idea is right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ad-hoc is the right way to think of it. Use **Ralink RT3570** Driver based WiFi Adapters to achieve ad hoc mode. I do not use Windows 10 IoT so I could not help further but the initial idea is right.

---

<sup>Started as Community Wiki answer based on Shan-Desai's comment from Mar 6 '16. Feel free to edit or add your own answer.</sup>